# BeautifulSoup table object with rowspan to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, html, csv, pandas, beautifulsoup

I read a html table with beautifulsoup which contains rowspans. When parsed into a panda dataframe, it is not sensible expanded as the rowspan declaration is not sensibly treated. My code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

tables = BeautifulSoup(open('out.html','r').read(),'lxml').findAll('table')
df = pd.read_html(str(tables[1]))

df[0].to_csv('out.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf8')
print(df)
```

However, the csv makes no sense, as the rowspan is

- not expanded to fill empty cells OR
- the CSV contains at most the number of columns; Instead it contains many more columns, which seem to be created as the rowspan is not been taken into consideration.

Both files are on this gist https://gist.github.com/the42/713425cdcc2cd5796bf9284fee78d4e5

Comment: Your input only has one table, also the encoding looks wrong in the html, pretty sure `â€` is not what it is meant to be.

Comment: This is only a snippet of the whole input. Anyhow, it is the minimal example to showcase the problem. Without encoding specification it thas to be manually set to utf8 in which case the characters become clear.